# TinyMCE: experiences, options

Tags: php, javascript, textbox, tinymce

I am considering using TinyMCE to handle the textboxes on sites I develop. I have the production version downloaded.

At first I will be using it for the backend of a client's site on a deadline and I need it to work out of the box initally. In the future I also like the customisation options.

Basically, does TinyMCE work, is it stable and is it cross browser compatible in a normal server environment?

I am a PHP developer with limited Javascript skills.

Comment: There are a lot of large projects that use tinyMCE.  WP mentions Wordpress Drupal and Joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/using.php) a list of people who are using Tinymce. In other words, yes it works, its stable and cross browser compatible.